# How can the Orcs be so easily killed?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit, tolkiens-legendarium, orcs

Orcs can be slayed with very little effort even by the un-warrior humans, despite their fully developed figures, average-to-tall heights, muscular bodies. (See The Hobbit series, where a dwarf would dive into a herd of orcs and come out un-wounded and killing most of them). What could be the technical explanation?

Comment: Can you list some examples? The only example you did list was literally of *warrior* un-humans, not un-warrior humans. When do we see any non-warrior humans fight against Orcs?

Comment: Oh dear...as with most movie answers: 'cause Peter Jackson.

Comment: @CreationEdge, the Bard's un-warrior, non-adult son.

Comment: @PaulDraper If that's in the most recent movie, I haven't seen it yet, and I don't recall it in the book.

Comment: @CreationEdge, it is. And I suspect the OP is pulling heavily from that movie.

Comment: Yes I was referring to the very fisherman's village(I forgot the name of the town) dwellers in the last movie. Bard's son as well as other non-warrior human beings.

Comment: That "village" name is Lake Town.

Comment: So, you weren't satisfied with the way events in the movie were Orc-estrated?

Comment: Orcs are actually not of average-to-tall height. In general they are shorter than Men.

Comment: You might want to clarify if you're discussing the books or the films. The Orcs in the books are nowhere near as easily dispatched as those in the films, of whom there are only three that seem to pose any challenge to a being, of any species, who is not both crippled and suffering dysentry.

Comment: Orcs are the bad guys. They die easy for the same reason the Stormtroopers in Star Wars have terrible aim and get massacred by Ewoks.

Comment: One thing that's being left out is that warriors who fight with blades like that or hand to hand, even in the real world's modern day, are trained to fight someone of equal height or taller, for some reason, not shorter.  So, when you are 6' tall fighting someone 3'-4' tall, it's incredibly hard to hit them because you no longer have a point of reference.  You're having to change everything about how you fight just to try to hit this tiny 'person' who is constantly swinging his/her own fists/blades at you.

Comment: Plus, it doesn't matter what race you are, if someone stabs/cuts you, it's going to hurt and it's still possible to die from being stabbed in the head by someone who is an 'un-warrior'.

Comment: @Robert, are you sure?  I am a competitive sword and shield fighter and have not noticed difficulty in fighting shorter fighters other than them having more of their body guarded by the same size shield.

Comment: @Stefan, you fight people that are 3-4 feet tall when you practice?  Because that's the average height of a dwarf or hobbit.  My guess is that you fight someone a couple inches taller or shorter than yourself.  Try doing so with someone that's about 3 feet tall and see how difficult it actually is.

Comment: Personally, I think it's a rather silly question as asked. The orcs are muscular and in shape, therefore how are they killed so easily? A sword to the gut will kill the biggest athlete out there just as easily as it would the skinny nerd.

Comment: @Robert,Hmmm ... true, I cannot think of any time I have fought someone quite that short.  However, I have fought on steps and on split levels such that my opponents were lower than me by about that amount.  In some ways it makes things easier as I could just rain shots down on the heads like I was hammering in tent pegs whilst they had difficulty reaching anywhere that might stop me (nb I wear two separate, overlapping, layers of groin protection).  If they were 3 feet tall then their limbs would be shorter too which gives me longer range as well as easy access to their head.

Comment: @Stefan being on steps is a little different because then you're actually accounting for the fact that someone is at a lower level than you.  You're no longer "fighting" on equal terms as you have the high ground in that scenario.  Also, the fact that their limbs are shorter means that they would be closer to you, which means that you are actually over reaching them.  Much like how a grappler has the advantage against a striker when he'she gets in close to an opponent.

Comment: @Robert, but I would also account for them being lower than me if they are that much shorter.  Their limbs being shorter does not mean they are automatically closer. They have to get through several attacks before they can do anything at all, any one of which might kill them and I am unlikely to stay still if they are closing in. I have experienced people trying exactly that many times. They need to be very good to pull it off.

Comment: Having a big armour for sure makes a difference too for getting close. Like I said in my answer, in Tolkien's Middle Earth, dwarves are always well protected by very good armour, which is not the case with orcs. They are also the most sturdy of all races and really strong. Which makes every one of them a "tank" by video game standards. Not easy opponents.

Comment: as for children, that is all in Peter Jackson's head... I may be mistaken for having a bad memory, but don't remember children fighting succesfully in a man's war in any of Tolkien book. Hobbits are the closest you can find, and they tend to fight by stealth and cunning more than in frontal attacks. Interesting discussion though... :-)

Comment: @Omegacron Brilliant logic. You should go explain that to a US ground infantry drill sergeant. They seem to think soldiers will do better if they are in good shape.

Comment: @MishaRosnach - well, in general they will... just not against bullets & knives. But even drill sergeants know that half their job is brainwashing the kids into thinking they're immortal badasses.

Comment: @Omegacron Actually, someone in top shape has a much chance of surviving a stab or bullet wound, as well as the strength to fight longer after they got stabbed or shot. So yes, against bullets and knives too. Also, stuff happens before you get stabbed. If you're out of breath and slow after two swings and a dodge, you are not gonna be the last man standing.

Comment: Check out DA ORKS from warhammer 40 000... Those are real "orcs"... WAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGH!

Answer (score 56):

I must admit that it's true in the movies they look like having a hopeless advantage. BUT...

*Spoilers follow:*

1. > Most of the battle orcs depicted in the movie seem to be Uruk-hai, the bigger breed of orcs from Mordor or Orthanc. But in the book, they were not, only the usual smaller breed of orcs, like we actually see in the second wave in the movie, the one conducted by Bolg. Men and elves are much bigger and stronger than those orc races. Also, orcs don't have good equipment like we see in the movie... they are not disciplined...
2. > They don't have all those big monster trolls, and those pterodactyl like big war birds, which are in fact much smaller bats in the book, even though they are big for bats and numerous enough to be like clouds which bring terror to the battlefield, they don't actually have the kind of size or raw power shown in the movie. (Thanks to Keen for raising the point about the bats, which I had forgotten.)
3. > They don't have those earth eaters worms (probably inspired by Dune) or I don't know what Peter Jackson calls them in English.
4. > In the book, the men from Lake Town in the battle are trained warriors, not civilians. This is a part of Middle-earth called "The Wild", and it's a very dangerous place, not a peaceful setting. Men living there are used to battle.
5. As depicted in the movie, dwarves in Tolkien's world are redoubtable warriors, with much steadfastness... they are really strong and can endure a lot. They are disciplined and they are masters of iron work, so they have really good equipment.
6. > In the book, the elves, dwarves and men know the orcs are coming and have time to prepare, Gandalf, Thranduil, Bard and Dáin devise a plan of attack, they array their troops on the heights north and south of the valley and the orcs don't enter the battlefield by tunnels, but in a frontal attack by the mouth of the valley without much strategy as is their custom, and are attacked on both sides, first by the elves, then by the dwarves and men on the other side. The orcs are massacred right there and would be crushed if it wasn't for the second wave that then came attacking the spurs from the top of the mountain after a climb of the other side.

But what would then maybe have been a lost battle for the dwarves, men, and elves is saved by the arrival of the eagles and Beorn (the man shape shifter who is also a big bear). Beorn gets to kill Bolg, the orc supreme general, and the battle is won there.

So, yes, there is much "Peter Jackson" in this battle, Hollywood style - Tolkien was way more realistic.

Comment: I stopped reading after #3.  Please wrap it in a spoiler tag since it's specific to the latest film.

Comment: Can't be Uruk-hai as those are bred by Saruman, *much* later...

Comment: @RLH: here you are, sorry about that.

Comment: @DevSolar: Uruks are first bred by Sauron in TA 2475, right after his return.

Comment: saruman rediscovers how to breed the uruk-hai in the years preceeding the lord of the rings or is taught.(though im pretty sure it says he rediscovered)

Comment: #2 is partially incorrect. Those were bats, and they were in the book.

Comment: @Keen, yes you are right, good point, I edited my answer, thank you.

Comment: Did anyone else find it ironic how the ancient wise elven king charges in on a giant elk lopping off heads, while the mad dog Azog stays back to command his troops from a safe vantage point?

Comment: Yes, good point Mikey Mouse... another Peter Jacksonry. In the book, first there is no Azog who as by then long been dead at the hands of the dwarves, and Bolg fights right in the middle of the action with his personnal bodyguard, that consists of the only Uruks that are mentionned.

Comment: BTW, both elves and dwarfs are long living races. They should have more battle experience that orcs by far.

Comment: "[...]those earth eaters worms (probably inspired by Dune)[...]" I would say  "blatantly plagiarized from Dune" instead.

Comment: @Sulthan: it's not really clear, but Orcs also seem to be long lived races, maybe as long lived as elves for those that  might be twisted elves as implied in the Silmarillon. And they fight all the time. But they sure are indisciplined.

Comment: Jackson's work in Trilogy is passable but poor.  His work on the Hobit, as this post illustrates, completely undermines the story and makes a mockery of it.

Comment: @nick PJ just nods his head on the way to the bank.

Comment: @Sulthan: don't know if Tolkien mentionned the longevity of orcs anywhere, but there is one exemple we know about: Bolg, son of Azog, was the leader of the orcs of the Misty Mountains for 150 years after the death of his father Azog. He was certainly full grown when his father died in the war between orcs and dwarves. And he also died in battle, not by old age, so we can expect orcs to be able to live for 200 years and more.

Comment: If I already had little interest in watching the Hobbit films, this answer completely nailed it. Dune worms? Really?

Comment: @MajorStackings +1 for that.  So many lemmings handing over the cash.

Answer (score 22):

Though this may have been more exaggerated in the movies, this is the case in the LOTR books as well. Recall Gimli's and and Legolas's contest at Helm's Deep which Gimli won 42-41 (or 43-42 in the movie).

Possible reasons for the individual inferiority (perceived or actual) of orcs:

- Orcs are ugly, half-crippled, corrupted spawn of Morgoth's making. It's not surprising if they are less skilled than a elf, man, or dwarf. Eru/Aulë did better than Morgoth.
- Throughout the LOTR/Hobbit movies and books, Sauron relies on surprise and overwhelming numbers in battles, not skill or finesse. He and his generals have little regard for the value of an orcish life, and they frequently strategize for  Pyrrhic victories.
- Orcs are greedy, selfish, disloyal, and lazy. You can expect them to fight more like rabble and less like a well-organized army.
- In the LOTR, orcs attack fortified positions. Man-to-man (or man-to-orc), that is a significant disadvantage.
- Our heros, with the exception of perhaps the hobbits, are not ordinary warriors. Gandalf is a Maiar and one of only 5 wizards. Legolas is an immortal elf and son of King Thranduil. Thorin is the heir to line of Thror. Bard is a descendent of the Lord of Dale. Boromir is the son of the steward of Gondor. And so on. In the Tolkien-verse, royalty such as these are significantly more powerful (in battle and otherwise) than a random peasant.

Comment: Originally Morgoth made them, not Sauron.

Comment: I would put more emphasis on the lack of skill/finesse. The depiction of Orcs during Sam's POV when Frodo is captured in Mordor shows them as greedy, selfish, and maybe even lazy. These aren't really qualities that lend themselves to disciplined training and combat practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments. I understand an author can not give up the main characters with important storylines for a realistic battle fight but still Orcs could be rendered (in the movies) a bit more deadly. @CreationEdge, I agree that laziness and lack of combat practice might have made a huge difference.

Comment: I wouldn't agree orcs are generally "less powerful than elf, man of dwarf". Recall how Uglúks company (even the smaller mountain goblins therein) outruns the pursuit by Legolas, Aragorn and Gimli (who each were certainly rather powerful amongst their kind); so at least in terms of endurance-running orcs pretty much excel. They're also described (albeit by hobbits) as "terribly strong" and with quick reflexes. The main weakness of groups of orcs is always their horrible social behaviour.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, running faster doesn't mean much. By that measure, horses would be even more powerful.

Comment: leftaroundabout has a point there... it's true that Tolkien made explicit that orcs have great endurance and are quite strong. But ordinary orcs are still no match for elves, dwarves and human warriors, so they always rely on greater numbers. Uruks are something else, but will still be defeated in equal numbers by high elves or numenoreans/dunedains. But even then, they still trail far behind in terms of tactics and strategy. Which in the end is often the main decisive elements in winning or losing battles between sizable armed forces.

Comment: Helm's Deep isn't really a fair comparison... that was  an extremely fortified position where any attacker was expected to take hugely disproportionate losses.

Comment: @MartianInvader, correct. I do mention that. On more even ground, the ratios would have been more even. (Though the last Hobbit movie had a relatively level playing field, and lots of orcs died...but that's "only" the movie.)

Answer (score 10):

There is much evidence that the original orcs would be closer to what we usually call goblins. Tolkien did not differentiate between the two words and treated them as synonymous; the official explanation being (in the preface to The Hobbit) that 'orc' was the hobbit word and 'goblin' was the human one.

Perhaps that helps you to imagine the original race not as man sized hulking beings like those who have become Uruk-Hai, but as a somewhat more chaotic and physically weaker lot.

Answer (score 5):

Also bear in mind even the larger Uruk-hai orcs were not (in the book) particularly large relative to men.  They are described as being 'almost man-sized' when their great size was spoken of, which means normal orcs were considerably smaller than humans and possibly dwarves also.

The movies tend to follow the hollywood formula of one hero or a few heroes overcoming masses of bad guys.  In the book the battle scenes were not so simplistic.  The only time I can recall the characters taking major risks was when they were attacked in Moria in the Chamber of Mazarbul, where they hoped a quick, spirited attack may surprise the orcs temporarily and thereby buy them some time to escape, and when Aragorn led his army to Mordor to initiate an attack.  When they were attacked on the banks of the Anduin, they had no option but to defend themselves, and some survived because the orcs hot-footed away with their prizes (Merry and Pippin).

Orcs may not have been the most disciplined, but they had numbers and a strong miltary culture.  There were formidable enemies and your question is more a reflection on the unbelievably ridiculous action scenes we have to endure in all hollywood movies.