# Why did Peter Jackson increase the number of kills by Legolas and Gimli by one?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, behind-the-scenes, adaptation-comparison

According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/77349/20393) :

> Recall Gimli's and and Legolas's contest at Helm's Deep which Gimli won **42-41** (or **43-42** in the movie).

We all know that the books and movie differ in many places, but this particular instance seems especially pointless.

Is it ever explained why Peter Jackson increased the number of kills by 1 for each character?

Comment: To adjust for inflation? ;)

Comment: Oh if that were the only pointless deviation from the books...

Comment: He had to account for the Mumakil.

Comment: @Omegacron ah, so Legolas didn't kill that giant elephant thing in the books?

Comment: That's a completely different battle.

Comment: Because the films are nonsense.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I remember rightly the statistic is never read out in the book. Legolas and Gimli are reunited after they get separated and Gimli says:

> "Forty-two, Master Legolas!" he cried.  "Alas! My axe is notched; the forty-second had an iron collar on his neck. How is it with you?"
>
> "You have passed my score by one," answered Legolas. "But I do not grudge you the game, so glad am I to see you on your legs!"

When you're writing a script from notes in the book it's easier to imagine someone noting down the number 42, then a note "score passed by one" or something like that, but adding one instead of removing one.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but it's more of an opinion than an answer.

Comment: It started as a comment but go too long including the quote, if someone comes up with any better explanation I'll delete it, but I thought it was worth mentioning

Comment: Perhaps the only reason the numbers were increased is that one of the scriptwriters thought 43-42 sounds better than 42-41.

Comment: I added the exact quote for you.

Comment: Interesting that script writing & computer programming have 2 things in common: off-by-one errors.

Comment: "Why can't people just learn to live together in peace and harmony?" said Legolas. Gimli gave a loud, very hollow laugh. "Forty-two, Master Legolas!" he cried. "Alas! Doesn't work, never mind." --*The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Shire*